# How to put a quotation box wrapped in text?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, quoting

What is the easiest way to put a box for quotation wrapped within text as we do for `figure` with `wrapfig`. Like half-sized box of text in magazines. I am trying `float`, but I am not sure if it is the best choice for this purpose.

I am looking for a flexible solution: When the box content is long, split the box in two pages (continues to the next page along with the main text).

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you have in mind?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you mean with "wrapped in text". I can't see how `figure` is doing this.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Exactly! `figure` is what I need, but I am not sure if `figure` is the best choice for text.

Comment: I still don't get it. The floating object created by the `figure` environment is not wrapped in text at all. Are you talking about a specific package?

Comment: @StephanLehmke sorry I meant `wrapfig`. In the original question, I referred to the possibility to wrap `figure` by corresponding packages. And I am asking for the best package to wrap a box of text.

Comment: Ok, understood. The corresponding environment is called `wrapfigure`. Please edit your question accordingly. Furthermore maybe you also mean `wrapfloat` instead of `float`? However, they will not break over pages for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might have misunderstood the question... but I think you want to *wrap* the quotation within text. It can be achieved using `wrapfig` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{l}{.5\textwidth}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
%\centering
``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Proin ac tempus dui. Etiam non mattis neque. Maecenas tempor,
massa a luctus sollicitudin, elit massa auctor velit, eu mattis
lacus arcu nec est. 

Sed et lectus non tellus posuere consequat.
Donec congue lacinia urna a iaculis. Cras id nisl sed sapien
euismod rhoncus.''
\end{minipage}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the box to span many pages, then the `mdframed` option suggested in the other answer should be followed.

Answer (score 2):

Floats cannot wrap multiple pages. I would recommend the [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package for this purpose.